# How to calculate the probability of pairings in a group?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have one group with $5$ elements: the numbers $3, 5, 7, 11, 13$
and a second group with another $5$ elements: the numbers $6, 10, 14, 22, 26$

Each number from group $1$ needs to be paired with its respective multiple in group $2$.

If each element from group $1$ is paired at random with an element in group two, what is the probability the elements are paired correctly?

For this type of counting, are we doing $5!$ ? Therefore the probability is $1/120$?

Next, assume all the $10$ elements are in one group and are being paired at random. Is the number of possible pairings $\frac{10!}{5!2^5}$?

I am reviewing counting methods for a course and I want to be sure I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is exactly one correct way and $5!$ ways to group them overall. But for when they are in the same group of course the probability will be even less than before, so $1/45$ is not correct. You must choose $2$ numbers to be put together repeatedly until there are none left: $\binom {10}{2} \binom{8}{2} \binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$ combinations so the probability is $5!/\binom {10}{2} \binom{8}{2} \binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$ since by my comment below we overcount each possbility by a factor of $5!$. This is assuming a number can't pick itself.

Comment: After reviewing this problem again, why isn't the possible number of pairings $\frac{10!}{5!2^5}$?

Comment: I am sorry, I believe in the previous way I miscounted by counting in such a way that the order matters (Choosing numbers $(1,3)$ then $(3,4)$... is the same as choosing $(3,4)$ then $(1,2)$) so we must divide by $5!$ since there is no distinction between these possibilities in the final set of pairings.

Comment: I believe you meant to say $\frac{\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{5!}$. This will give you the same result as what I posted in the question!

Comment: Well what I have is the probability, the number of combinations is what you posted.

Comment: Since there is only $1$ "correct" pairing, the probability will be the multiplicative inverse of the number of combinations.